# laravel5.1 basic http auth for API

Tags: php, http, authentication, laravel-5.1, http-authentication

I'm working on a web based API. For this I don't need the overloaded feature of laravel to use a table for storing the login details of the http auth. I just would like to protect one function (so middleware would be overloaded too) by using a hardcoded username & password for HTTP auth.

All I found at the moment doesn't work, isn't there a simple code example how to do so? All I found in tutorials is using the users table, but for my API this would be overloaded, since I only need one account which I would like to hardcode into the controller.

Comment: It may seem overkill, but if you are wanting to secure something you properly shouldn't take it too lightly nor overlook some of the more overkill approaches for this. Having recently done this myself, I would suggest storing an API key of some sort, or use a username and password in the `User` table and then send this in your request - you can then just use middleware to check for this. It's actually quite simple to get set up and super secure.

Answer (score 0):

Pass username & password in headers with every call, and check with the hardcoded credentials in controller's constructor.

Example:

```
use use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyController extends Controller
{
  public function __construct(Request $request)
  {
    parent::__construct();

    $username = $request->header('username');
    $password = $request->header('password');
    if($username !== 'Your Hardcoded username' || $password !== 'Hardcoded password') {
      throw new \Exception;
    }
  }
}
```